# Rake spec fails with no error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, redhat, specifications

I have a Rails app that runs on Phusion+Apache in the following environment:

RHEL 5 x64
   Ruby 1.9.2 p290 x64
   Rails 3.0.4
   Rake 0.9.2.2

I'm using and Oracle 11g database so I've also installed:

- activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.4.0)
- ruby-oci8 (2.0.6)

database.yml is correctly configured.

My application correctly runs in production mode.

The problem is when I try to run my tests with rake spec I have the following Warnings and then the rake process stops with **no error message** at all.

Here is the output:

```
alex@rhel:~/projects/app$ rake spec
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
    at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb
WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
    ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
WARNING: DSL method Api::Application#task called at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize_tasks'
alex@rhel:~/projects/app$
```

I've checked the exit code of the rake process and is set on 0 -> success.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are deprecation warnings, informing you that some of the code you're calling has been deprecated.

Are your tests actually failing? Getting deprecation warnings doesn't mean you spec is failing. I see three dots `... Rake::DSL`

Are those dots your passing specs? How many specs do you have?

Comment: This is my actual problem that I have no output from the rake spec command. As you can see from my cmd line it is just exiting with no error message at all *after displaying some warning messages*. The three dots are from the Warning message it's not from the tests. The testing does not begin at all. I have about 10+ specs.

Comment: Try rspec directly and use -c -fd flags? Just to see if you get different output that direction...